# Using variable font in Flutter only show FontWeight.w400 or FontWeight.w600 for every FontWeight

Tags: flutter, fonts

I'm facing a problem trying to use any Variable Font downloaded from fonts.google.com

Here is the result I get:
[image: Result using variable font]

Expected result (obtained using multiple fixed font files):
[image: Result using multiple files]

Here is the code used:

- Page:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: FontWeight.values
          .map(
            (weight) => Text(
              'This text has weight $weight',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: weight),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

App:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  home: ...,
  theme: ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Sono',
  ),
)
```

pubspec:

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  ...

  fonts:
    - family: Sono
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Sono-VariableFont.ttf
```

Tried a lot of things, like wrapping my app in a `DefaultTextStyle` or changing the `fontVariations` parameter. No effect on the variable fonts.

Comment: can you include FontWeight List too?

Comment: I use `FontWeight.values` to iterate over the weights. So basically it's `[FontWeight.w100, FontWeight.w200, FontWeight.w300, FontWeight.w400, FontWeight.w500, FontWeight.w600, FontWeight.w700, FontWeight.w800, FontWeight.w900]`

Comment: The sono doesnt contain w100

Comment: could you print("FontWeight = $FontWeight"); an show me the result?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh You are right about this font, but tried earlier with 'Inter' and got the same result

Comment: @eamirho3ein `flutter: FontWeight = [FontWeight.w100, FontWeight.w200, FontWeight.w300, FontWeight.w400, FontWeight.w500, FontWeight.w600, FontWeight.w700, FontWeight.w800, FontWeight.w900]`

Comment: I can't call `values` on this list. are you suer you list contains FontWeight? @ndelanou

Comment: I had some similar issue, some font doesn't provide all weight

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Well, this shouldn't be a problem because I'm using a Variable Font. One file for every weights

Comment: can you attach the font link

Comment: @eamirho3ein Using the beta channel, Flutter 3.4.0

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Sono

Comment: @eamirho3ein https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontWeight/values-constant.html

Comment: Try to specify the font weight on assets and run with html render.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `FontVariation` property of TextStyle widget.

```dart
FontWeight.values
  .map(
    (weight) => Text(
      'This text has weight $weight',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontVariations: [
          FontVariation(
              'wght', ((weight.index + 1) * 100).toDouble())
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
  .toList(),
```

Output
[image: Output]

Comment: It works pretty well.
Waiting in the case someone got a solution directly using the `fontWeight` parameter before accepting the answer.

Comment: I ended up reading a lot about font variations. This font looks like uniwidth in variable form. I can see on https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Sono?query=sono that each letter takes same horizontal space for all fontweights which is not the case when you used multiple fixed font files. I wanted to fix that but haven't yet. I ended up reading https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/glossary/multiplexed_duplexed_uniwidth
Thanks for your question.

Comment: Yeah, this works but we need the canonical way

Answer (score 0):

After reading flutter documentation and OpenType(font file) I reached a conclusion, that flutter or some of fonts are just broken and the best option to be able to use fontWeight and fontStyle properties it's to statically define fonts.

In flutter docs [**Declare the font in the pubspec**](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts#2-declare-the-font-in-the-pubspec) is described how to do this.

file: `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

So we use static fonts with 3 parameters path, weight and style(normal/italic).

I think it will be the most accrued solution, because we directly say witch font we want for given weight/style.

But now we would need to define dozens of files. I have small, not ideal solution for this. Python script to generate this yaml properties.

```py
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import yaml

asset_prefix = "assets/fonts/"
root = "Montserrat/static"

def bitfields(n):
    fields = [1 if digit=='1' else 0 for digit in bin(n)[2:]]
    fields.reverse()
    return fields 

def read_os_2(file):
    with TTFont(join(root, file)) as font:
        os_2 = font['OS/2']
        fsSelection = bitfields(os_2.fsSelection)
        is_italic = fsSelection[0] == 1
        return {
            'asset': asset_prefix + file,
            'weight': os_2.usWeightClass,
            'style': 'italic' if is_italic else 'normal'
        }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = []
    for file in listdir(root):
        results.append(read_os_2(file))

    results_sorted = sorted(results, key=lambda elem: elem['weight'], reverse=True)
    print(yaml.dump(results_sorted))
```

**To run this script u need [fonttools](https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/)!**
In this script u need to define *root* directory where all of one font's files are stored and asset_prefix where u need to define prefix that will be add to path property.

sources:

- [os2-spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2)
- [fonttools](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttLib/ttFont.html#id0)
- [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts#2-declare-the-font-in-the-pubspec)